# How to group select in a column in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm newbie in sqlserver. I have a table named as UserTransactions.

```
WinnerWeek   UserGSM 
w1           1000000001
w2           1000000002
w2           1000000003 
w2           1000000002
w2           1000000003 
w2           1000000003 
w2           1000000003 
w3           1000000004
w3           1000000005
w3           1000000005
w3           1000000005
w4           1000000005
w4           1000000002
```

I want produce this output as shown below. But, how can I do it. Please, if possible give me sql query, thanks.

```
WinnerWeek   UserGSM       WeeklyCount
w1           1000000001     1
w2           1000000002     2
w2           1000000003     4
w3           1000000004     1
w3           1000000005     3
w4           1000000005     1
w4           1000000002     1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT WinnerWeek, UserGSM AS SmsSending, Count(*)
FROM UserTransactions
GROUP BY WinnerWeek, UserGSM
```

Comment: no, this query same with @kannan. could you please can you do it in sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly group by and get this count:

```
Select WinnerWeek, SmsSending, Count(*) from yourtable
   group by WinnerWeek, SmsSending
```

Comment: @JohnLin - Based on your data and this query, you should not get only 1 for  count columns.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` will work in unison to get this for you.

```
SELECT 
    winnerweek
    ,usergsm
    ,COUNT(*) AS weeklycount
FROM UserTransactions
GROUP BY 
    winnerweek
    ,usergsm
ORDER BY winnerweek
```

Please read the following so that you can understand this.

> GROUP BY: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql
>
> ORDER BY: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    WinnerWeek
    ,usergsm,count(WinnerWeek) as WeeklyCount 
FROM usertransactions 
GROUP BY WinnerWeek,usergsm
```

'Id' should be the primary key in the table